# Intergation between Jmeter and HP ALM

Tags: performance, jmeter, alm

Has anyone tried to Integrate HP ALM with JMeter? Very new to HP ALM so not sure on how to integrate it with JMeter.

On high level following functionality should work

1. trigger test with HP ALM
2. Execute test(test will run through JMeter)
3. Result should be uploaded on HP ALM

Any information regarding this would be helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no integration with JMeter in ALM.
But you can implement required functionality using [OTA API](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/webframe.html)

You can obtain a `TSScheduler` object from a `TestSet` object by calling `TestSet::StartExecution(IList)` method and pass it `IList` of `ITSTests`. After this you can do `TSScheduler::Run()` to run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Agiletestware Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee). It allows to send JUnit/TestNG reports to HP ALM and also provides integration on source code level with a set of Java annotations.

Disclaimer: I'm developer of Bumblebee